# Redirect pattern matching when testing in IIS, but not in browser

Tags: iis, url-rewrite-module

I've got the following redirect set up for a site in IIS, but it doesn't seem to work at all. The reason for the redirect is to get rid of an old Classic ASP site, so ideally I don't want to have that file there at all. Without the file I get a 404 error, with the file (and the mimetype mapped to text/html) I get the contents of the file as normal html. Nothing happens, and the server response is always returned as HTTP 200.

I would expect a request for `interface.asp?method=AMethod&Plant=APlant&AParameter=AValue` to be redirected to `example.org/interface/AMethod/APlant/AValue`

Testing the pattern in the IIS admin manager with the same URL I'm trying to open gives me the expected matches, is there something obvious I'm missing somewhere?

```
<rule name="interface redirect" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url=".+interface.asp\?method=(.+)&amp;Plant=(.+)&amp;(.+)=(.+)" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://example.org/interface/{R:1}/{R:2}/{R:4}" appendQueryString="false" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
</rule>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rule pattern only gets the URL string, doesn’t include the query string. Therefore, in the URL pattern, we should try to match the URL path instead of the query string. the query string should be matched in the `Rule Condition` by using the `Query_String` server variable.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-configuration-reference#accessing-url-parts-from-a-rewrite-rule
[image]
[image]
Based on your URL rule, I rectified it. Feel free to let me know if the problem still exists.

```
<system.webServer>
           <rewrite>
            <rules>
              <rule name="MyRule" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url=".*interface.asp" ignoreCase="false" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                    <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="method=(.+)&amp;Plant=(.+)&amp;(.+)=(.+)" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="http://example.org/interface/{C:1}/{C:2}/{C:4}" redirectType="Permanent" />
              </rule>
            </rules>
          </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
```

Comment: Superb! Funny how easy it is to overlook basic things once you've stared at a problem for too long... :p